# How to show element in table row if I have multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a table with multiple rows and in each row I have a form with id="saveComment". (target: for each row I want add comment)

I save data using AJAX. 
When I add comment I successfully save data in database for single comment in table as I need. But I additionally want to add an image element or show hidden image or some text in row where current submitted form is! (comment added - show image or success text which shows that row has a comment). And ideally hide image/text when comment become empty

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="success"><span id="successmessage" style="display:none;">OK</span></td>
        <td>
            <form method="post" id="saveComment">
                <!-- some form data and submit button -->
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

AJAX:

```
<script>
    var frm = $("#saveComment");
        frm.submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: frm.attr('method'),
                contentType: "application/json",
                crossDomain: true,
                async: true,
                url: 'test.cgi',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Saved!');
                    $("#successmessage").show();
                    console.log('Submission was successful.');
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('Error!');
                    console.log('An error occurred.');
                    console.log(data);
                },
            });
        });
</script>
```

If I add in ajax code in success function $("#successmessage").show(); I show message only in the first form on page, not for current submitted form

How to show/add image or text for the desired entry only where form were submitted?

Comment: can i know what u exactly want?

Comment: @BathriNathan i want to change some elements, e.g. show message that data saved successfully, using jquery after submitting. Now if i submitting form - ajax data transmitted normally, but e.g. $("#successmessage").show(); in my jquery part of code doesn't shows message in currently submitted form, but shows it in the first form of the page

Comment: @BathriNathan and now i have found solution adding `var id = $(this).attr("id")`, and `$("#successmessage_"+id).show();` (and changed my span to `<span id="successmessage_45600"` - 45600 is a unique number equal my form id). But this solution seems to be ugly

Comment: please check my below answer it might help you to under stand the problem with your code.that what i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the success function, you can target the element that triggered the form submission. I am assuming there is a submit button. so the code can be some thing like this.

```
$(e.target).parents('tr').find('#successimageid').show();
```

Additionally, Using same id multiple times in a page is a wrong idea. id is an unique identifier and hence there should be one and only one in a page.

Comment: Hi. Thank's. I'm noob in JQuery. If I add unique id for each form, e.g. id of user, how my jquery part of code should be changed? And how to do same thing with show image or text in this case?

Comment: what about $('.form').on('submit', function(){ var id = $(this).attr('id'); $(id).html(text/image);  }) or something like that @Serg

Comment: @Ari Hi. Thank's for Your idea! `$(id).html('Success!');` doesn't works for me. Nothing  appears. I added unique id for form and additionally for image that i want to show if success, e.g. form id = #34567, and image id = #success_34567. And show() works as I need - only for submitted form (`var id = $(this).attr("id"); $("#success_"+id).show();`) One more question: is this a normal or standard solution to set unique ID not only for form but even for elements? Why Your solution doesn't work? May be I should use $(this) but i can't find examples in my case

Comment: @Serg for your use case, you could just use a class instead of id and everything should work just fine. And don't forget to change # with a dot(.).

Comment: @KireetiK No :( If I use class - changes are only in first row/form of my table, not in form I submitted.

Comment: @Serg Add a class .form to all your forms and a unique id to every single form. You don't need to give unique ID to elements.You can just do $(id).parent().parent().find("#successmessage").show();

Answer (score 1):

hey it might be your problem please do not use same id for multiple forms because it is unique, if you use same if for many form or div then only the first div or form will work. please refer the below example it will explain you

```js
$('#click').click(function() {
    //select all radio is now checked
        $('#event444').prop('checked', true);
        $('#reset').prop('checked', false);
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
//reset radio is now checked
    $('#click').prop('checked', false);
        $('#event444').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
  please select any of the radio button
  <input  type="radio" id="click" value="energyRating">select all
  <input  type="radio" id="reset" value="energyRating">reset all
</div>

<div id="b">
  <input  type="checkbox" id="event444"  value="Bike1">I have a bike<br>
  <input  type="checkbox" id="event444" value="Car">I have a car <br>
<input  type="checkbox" id="event444" value="Bike">I have another bike<br>
  <input  type="checkbox" id="event444" value="Car">I have another car
</div>
```

use classes to over code **id issue**.check the below code.

```js
    $('.click').click(function() {
        //select all radio is now checked
            $('.event444').prop('checked', true);
            $('.reset').prop('checked', false);
    });

    $('.reset').click(function() {
    //reset radio is now checked
        $('.click').prop('checked', false);
            $('.event444').prop('checked', false);
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="a">
      please select any of the radio button
      <input  type="radio" class="click" value="energyRating">select all
      <input  type="radio" class="reset" value="energyRating">reset all
    </div>

    <div id="b">
      <input  type="checkbox" class="event444"  value="Bike1">I have a bike<br>
      <input  type="checkbox" class="event444" value="Car">I have a car <br>
    <input  type="checkbox" class="event444" value="Bike">I have another bike<br>
      <input  type="checkbox" class="event444" value="Car">I have another car
    </div>
```

Comment: My English is too bad, but seems i can explain to You. See: You have 20 forms with class `myform`. In each `<form></form>` tags You have submit button and `<span style="display:none;">Success!</span>`. You have jquery code with ajax request. User presses submit button on, for example, form number 15 of 20. How You will show  <span> with success message only in that <form>, form number 15 where user clicked submit? Other <span>'s should stay invisible, because user doesn't pressed submit button there. Is it possible without unique ID for each <span> and <form>?

Comment: In Your second example I can either select all checkboxes, or unselect all of them. Same thing i get's if I use classes instead unique ID on my page. I think, unique id required for my task. E.g. `<form id=15 method=post><span style="display:none;" id='success_15'>Success!</span></form>`

Comment: @Serg if u need id then create unique id for everything. And handle them properly. But its better to use class if u have so many div or for basically. You can even handle particular div with index in the selector based on class example :$('event444').[0]  - - to select first element